# Versioned writeahead log - Does this data structure exist?

Tags: data-structures, database

**Background:**

I have read that many DBMSs use write-ahead logging to preserve atomicity and durability of transactions by storing updates as a group of write operations. What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a dbms model with improved concurrency by [allowing reads to proceed on 'old' data while writes are pending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control).

**Question:**

Is there a data structure that allows me to efficiently *(ideally O(1) amortized, at most O(log(n))* look up array elements (or memory locations, if you like), which may or may not have been overwritten by write actions, in reference to some point in time? This would be for about 1TB of data total.

Here is some ascii art to make this a little clearer. The dashes are data, with version 0 being the oldest version. The arrows indicate write operations.

```
 ^   ___________________________________Snapshot 2
 |   V         |  |     V                         
 |  --    ---  |  |  --------           Version 2 
 |             |  |   __________________Snapshot 1
 |             V  |   |      V                    
T|      --------  |   |   ---------     Version 1 
I|                |   |      ___________Snapshot 0
M|                V   V      V  V                 
E|------------------------------------- Version 0 
 +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~>
  SPACE/ADDRESS
```

**Attempts at solution:**

Let N be the data size, M be the number of versions, and P be the average number of updates per version.

- The naive algorithm (searching each update) is O(M*P).
- Dividing the data into buckets, updating only entire buckets, and searching a bitmask of buckets would be O(N/B*M), where B is bucket size, which isn't much better.
- A Bloom filter seems like a good candidate at first glance, except that it requires more data than a simple bitmask of each memory location (which would be bad anyway, since it requires M*N/8 bytes to store.)
- A standard hash table also comes to mind, but what would the key be?

*Actually, now that I've gone to the trouble of writing this all up, I've thought of a solution that uses a binary search tree. <strike>I'll submit it as an answer in a bit, but it's still O(M*log2(P)) in space and time which is not ideal.</strike> See below.*

Answer (score 0):

The following is the best solution I could come up with, though it is still suboptimal.

The idea is to place each region into a binary search tree, one tree per version, where each inner node contains a memory location, and each leaf node is either `Hit` or `Miss` (and possibly lookup information), depending on if updated data exists there. This is O(P*log(P)) to construct for each version, and O(M*log(P)) to look up in.

This is suboptimal for two reasons:

- The tree is balanced, but `Miss`es are much more likely than `Hit`s in practice, so it would make sense to put `Miss` nodes higher in the tree, or arrange nodes by their size. Some kind of Huffman coding comes to mind, but Huffman's algorithm does not preserve the search tree invariants.
- It requires M trees (hence O(M*log(P)) lookup). Maybe there is some way to combine the trees.